# Make new connections when blocked in a select() call

Tags: multithreading, sockets, select, networking, tcp

I have 2 threads:

Thread A:
It's the **select()** loop. Perform socket handling for reading operations, such as accepting new connections, receiving data.

```
while (1) {

    FD_ZERO(&fdReadSet);

    numActiveSockets = 0;

    for (std::unordered_map<SOCKET, TcpSocket*>::iterator it = m_sock_table.begin(); it != m_sock_table.end(); it++)
    {
        numActiveSockets++;
        FD_SET(it->first, &fdReadSet);
    }

    int ret;
    bool hasListen = false;

    if (( ret = select(numActiveSockets, &fdReadSet, NULL, NULL, NULL)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("Select Failed, Error code = %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        return -1;
    }

    for (std::unordered_map<SOCKET, TcpSocket*>::iterator it = m_sock_table.begin(); it != m_sock_table.end(); it++)
    {
        if (FD_ISSET(it->first, &fdReadSet))
        {
            if (it->first == TcpSocket::m_listen_sock)
            {
                if (!hasListen)
                {
                    sockaddr_in sock_addr;
                    int sockLength = sizeof(sock_addr);

                    SOCKET sock = accept(it->first, (sockaddr *) &sock_addr, &sockLength);
                    TcpSocket * socket = new TcpSocket();
                    socket->m_sock = sock;
                    m_sock_table[sock] = socket;

                    it = m_sock_table.begin();
                    hasListen = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                char * buffer = it->second->GetWriteBuffer();
                int numRead = recv(it->first, buffer, SOCKET_BUFFER_SIZE, 0);

                if (numRead == SOCKET_ERROR)
                {
                    int err = WSAGetLastError();
                    if (err == WSAECONNRESET)
                    {
                        printf("Connection [%i]: RESET Received. Closing Socket\n", it->first);
                        closesocket(it->first);
                        it = socketVector.erase(it->first);  // iterator invalidated after erase
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        printf("Recv Failed. Error code = %d\n", err);
                        return -1;
                    }
                }
                else if (numRead == 0)//connection close
                { 
                    printf("Connection [%i]: Graceful exit. Closing Socket\n", it->first);
                    closesocket(it->first);
                    it = socketVector.erase(it->first);  // iterator invalidated after erase

                }
                else {
                    /* Process received data */

                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thread B:
Allow the application  to perform **connect()** to establish new connections. If a **connect()** is successful, it will the add the returned socket to **m_sock_table**.

I have a socket table called **m_sock_table** which holds all the sockets. I use this **m_sock_table** to initialize the **fdReadSet** to be used in **select()**.

***-----------Problem-----------------***

If thread A is blocked by **select()**, and at the same time thread B establish a new connection through **connect()**, the application wouldn't be able to receive data from the new connection, because ***fdReadset*** has not been updated withed the new connected socket.

*What would be a good way to solve this problem? Or the design is just wrong from the start?*

Comment: What event causes new connections to be added? If you select() with a timeout, you could then add new connections to your table. You would then set the timeout to the acceptable latency between creating a connection and serving it.

Comment: Thanks. I end up using your method. If you are willing to post a answer, I happily mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a signal that doesn't do anything other than interrupting the system call:

```
#include <signal.h>
void do_nothing() { }

struct sigaction sa;
sa.sa_handler = do_nothing;
sigemptyset(sa.sa_mask);
#ifdef SA_INTERRUPT
sa.sa_flags = SA_INTERRUPT;
#else
sa.sa_flags = 0;
#endif
sigaction(SIGUSR1, &sa, 0);
```

Then, in thread B, after starting a new connection, send the signal, after making sure thread A will handle it:

```
/* need only be done once, but needed in every thread other than A */
sigset_t sigs;
sigemptyset(&sigs);
sigaddset(&sigs, SIGUSR1)
pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &sigs, 0);

/* each time we create a new connection */
kill(getpid, SIGUSR1);
```

With the above, select will return with an EINTR error -- so check for that and loop (adding the new connection to the set).

Comment: Signals are unfortunately non-portable beyond POSIX, otherwise that is a good approach with the only drawback that it awakes more threads than necessary (I think). If only need to port this to win32 systems additionally, you can use WSAEventSelect() to achieve something similar there.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: on win32, you should not use select at all, as it is unreliable.  You should instead use `WaitForMultipleObjects` where one of the objects is a message queue telling you to add more objects to the set of objects to wait for...

Comment: In what sense is select() unreliable on win32?

Comment: My apologies, I should have clarify I am working in Window System.  I think there's no way to interrupt select() call like this in windows?